# 10k users should not be able to dispute flags on their own answers/questions

Tags: feature-request, flags

I flagged an answer on [Assertion fails after using memcpy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554562/memcpy-issue-in-c) as "not an answer" because I felt it should have been a comment. The answer had been posted by a 10k+ user, and shortly after I flagged it the flag status changed to "disputed".

I assume the answerer disputed the flag themselves; I think that 10k+ users should not be able to dispute flags on their own content.

(In truth I suspect my own answer would have been better as a comment as well, but I only thought of that once I'd posted it, and I couldn't see any way for me to convert my own answer to a comment!)

Comment: `...I couldn't see any way for me to convert my own answer to a comment.` Delete or flag for deletion and repost as comment.

Comment: Are we talking about the two answers of Ernest? If yes, about which one? Both sound like valid answers to me, though, not the best...but the question isn't the best either.

Comment: What makes you think that the owner of the post was the one that disputed the flag?  There are other 10ks that can see the flags too you know.

Comment: @Padded Cell: It was the earlier answer Ernest posted, about the order of parameters of `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

10k users cannot see flags for their own posts. What happened is that other users who thought what posted as answer was really an answer voted your flag to be invalid.

Comment: "10k users cannot see flags for their own posts." - OK, that answers the question. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, it was *3* other users (not the person who posted) who voted to disagree with the flag /cc @Vicky